# What category does "Mathematical Optimization" and "Convex Optimization" belong to?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

[image]

The above image is from the book [*Optimization in Practice with MATLAB® for Engineering    Students and Professionals* (by Achille Messac, PhD), Page-94](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=F62wBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=In%20this%20section,%20we%20define%20the%20major%20classes%20of%20optimization%20problems,%20part%20of%20which%20is%20presented%20in%20Fig.%205.1.%20A%20general%20optimization%20problem%20can%20be%20formulated%20using%20the%20following%20set%20of%20equations%20(Refs.%20%5B1,%202%5D.&source=bl&ots=Kh96t9L9Sh&sig=wGJSkim9rQ6eOchTBAZep_QEZZk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKnbaljIveAhXF6Y8KHWuHDfcQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=true).

I don't see the terms such as [*Mathematical Optimization*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McLq1hEq3UY&list=PL3940DD956CDF0622) or [*Convex Optimization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) ([book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)) to be a part of this categorization.

What category do ***Mathematical Optimization*** and ***Convex Optimization*** belong to?

Comment: I'd put them in the non-linear category.

Comment: Mathematical optimization: everything. Convex optimization: blocks 1 and 2.

Comment: You could title this diagram "mathematical optimization" with convex optimization excluding the discrete case.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, is there anything called "non-mathematical optimization"?

Comment: @yahoo.com simulated annealing is just snake oil.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/833472/118539